# Is this another jQuery's bug or is it supposed to work this way?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

Is this another jQuery's bug or is it supposed to work this way?:

The `snap` option works as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/WsmVZ/

But with some margin added, it does not work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/WsmVZ/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447631/jquery-ui-draggable-not-dragging-from-the-correct-place @Nick Craver: might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

lol, you thought 100px was a reasonable margin for a 100px object? As the visible elements of the boxes approach each other it's trying to snap to two competing sides simultaneously.